Boolean Problems on Curved Surface
Hello Blender specialists!
ISSUE1
I am facing some problems with the Boolean Modifier (Difference) on a surface. I want to create an opening but I am getting the issue that the inner faces are not getting generated. I have tried both solvers (fast and exact) and only the fast gives me these results. With the exact solver NOTHING is happening. Moreover the mesh result after the operation is not looking really good and creating the faces manually would be very time consuming...
How I created this geometry? Well I just took the outer semi cycle section (only faces) and applied a 90 Degree Screw Modifier. I then extruded the lowest faces along Z and created the final shape. Creating an Opening at the non curved surface was not a problem, there everything functioned correctly! What can I do here?
ISSUE 2
I tried recreating the shape by applying the screw modifier at the outer edges only. This step was successful. The I tried applying the solidify modifier at this curved surface and I get some really crazy results. What is the method to give EVEN thickness to a surface like this? How can I use the EXTRUDE operation to perform this task?? Thank you!







You have internal edges, I mean edges that are inside the volume where they shouldn't. All the edges connecting the 2 surfaces should be deleted (with the exception of edges that are on the surface). More generally, boolean modifier expect a manifold geometry. Non-manifold geometries don't guarantee a correct result. Read more here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry
